# RPi lose internet connection

Tags: pi-3

I have just created a bridge connection with an openvpn installed as a client in my raspberry.  I have a **RPI3 B**, wit **debian 9** (stretch) ARM v7 processor.
What I don't understand is because it often loses the connection and I can't ping google, despite the wifi connection being activated. I tried removing the eth cable and reattaching it because it often created problems, but it remains so. among other things during this problem I still see my tunneled connections

This is the result of an **ip address** and an **ip route**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:2f:c7:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.169/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ab95:2f6c:7e2d:7222/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:7a:92:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2f37:37bc:e210:a98b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.3.XXX.XXX/24 brd 10.3.XXX.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fb2e::X/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.5.XXX.XXX/24 brd 10.5.XXX.255 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::43d9::X/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun2: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.4.XXX.XXX/24 brd 10.4.XXX.255 scope global tun2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::187e::X/64 scope link flags 800 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


root@raspberrypi:~# ip route
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.5.XXX.1 dev tun1 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.169 metric 202 
default via 192.168.1.190 dev wlan0 src 192.168.1.100 metric 303 
10.4.XXX.0/24 dev tun2 proto kernel scope link src 10.4.XXX.XXX 
10.5.XXX.0/24 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.5.XXX.XXX 
10.3.XXX.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.XXX.XXX 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.5.XXX.1 dev tun1 
185.104.184.XXX via 192.168.1.190 dev wlan0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.169 metric 202 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100 metric 303 
213.152.XXX.XXX via 192.168.1.190 dev wlan0 
213.152.XXX.XXX via 192.168.1.190 dev wlan0
```

@Ingo No preconfigured openvpn helper program, but the dist from resources. 
I no longer find the official version of my installed version

Comment: Having a WiFi access point with a wired uplink on a bridge used with an OpenVPN tunnel isn't an easy task. There are mainly seen routing problems or wrong configuration of the bridge. But with the information you have given I'm unable to see what may be wrong. At least you should edit your question and add the output of these commends: `ip addr` and `ip route`.

Comment: Do you use a preconfigured helper program for OpenVPN, something like PiVPN? Can you please give a link to the **Debian 9 for ARM processor**  distribution you are using?

Answer (score 0):

My wlan also kept sleeping. I found a few approaches to fixing it but in the end just added this to my /etc/profile

> sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

My Pi boots up headless and auto logs in so while it may not be the correct way, it seems to work.

Comment: Note that `/etc/profile` will not run if a user doesn't log in. So the autologin part here is probably crucial.

Comment: what do you mean as autologin?

Comment: In raspi-config, you can set it to automatically login at the terminal with the user "pi". That means you don't need a password when accessing locally